# Ruby combinations with ruleset & speed optimization?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, math, mathematical-optimization

Hey iam trying to figure out how i could limit my combinations of objects.

**My problem:**
I want to generate x teams with the most "point" outcome of 432 players, max team size is 7 players. Each player has an "position" attribute, every team must have each position one time and max 3 times. Also an player has an "worth" attribute. Each team cant be more worth than 70. Every player can only be one time in an team.

**Data example:**

```
{ name: 'James Harden', position: 'PG', weight: 15.9, points: 62.63 },
{ name: 'Russell Westbrook', position: 'PG', weight: 14.9, points: 56.12 },
{ name: 'LeBron James', position: 'SF', weight: 15.9, points: 55.67 },
{ name: 'Bradley Beal', position: 'SG', weight: 14.8, points: 52.69 },
{ name: 'Anthony Davis', position: 'PF', weight: 14.6, points: 52.16 },
{ name: 'Damian Lillard', position: 'PG', weight: 13.5, points: 49.34 },
{ name: 'Nikola Vucevic', position: 'C', weight: 12.9, points: 47.97 },
{ name: 'Domantas Sabonis', position: 'PF', weight: 12.8, points: 47.6 }
```

**My try:**
Well i tried to use the combination method from ruby:

```
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
print b.combination(7).to_a
```

that take 52 minutes for my laptop so solve all combinations. so i search for a way to do it faster an to apply more options like mentioned above to limit the result of teams.

Later if i find an solution i want to build this thing into an rails app with picture of the players and so on. Hopefully someone can give me an hint or has done something similar to give advices.

Also how would i controll to use more cpu kernels to speed up the proccess ?

Comment: This is not a problem that you would solve in Ruby in the first place. You would solve it by using a database and models...

Comment: You're going to have to attack this algorithmically if you want a speed boost like that, as computing combinations is really punishing for any large set. I'm surprised you could compute this at all considering there's 1,136,467,283,797,958,112,000 possibilities for 432 players.

Comment: As a place to start it sounds like you're dealing with the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). If you're not concerned with the optimal version you can always pick seven at random a million times and take the best qualifying result. If you must have the absolute optimal outcome you must come up with a more efficient algorithm than "try all combinations".

Comment: @tadman 
i only solved that combination of 30 numbers with the code above. i didnt even try it with 432 players because i know this number is to large. thats why iam seeking for optimisation.

yes i looked at the knapsack problem but the problem there is this problem is only for 2 values. i have some more with worth of the team, positions of a player and limitation of players in a team. there is now knapsack problem with more values than 2 i found so far.

Comment: Use Monte Carlo (pick at random) unless you need tease out the absolute ideal.